# Remote management on WRT630N via HTTPS

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ssl

I have a Linksys WRT630N wireless router and am trying to configure remote management via HTTPS. I've chosen a nonstandard port and can successfully connect and manage the router remotely via HTTP, but not via HTTPS. If I change the remote management option in the WRT630N config to "HTTPS", Chrome gives me ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when I change "http" to "https" in the URL, and trying the connection with openssl gives me "SSL handshake failed." Next steps?